# How to check whether a visitor has viewed an ad on Google Adsense?

Tags: php, post, adsense

I'm making a light PHP-based browser game (it's basically an interactive website with graphics). I definitely don't expect it to generate any income, but it'd be super if I could just get enough money to pay for monthly VPS hosting.

Instead of putting an ad on every single page, I decided to have a separate section where users can choose to view ads for a small reward. I'm looking at Google Adsense as an option for accomplishing this, but I'm not familiar with how I might implement this.

Is there any way I could check to see if a visitor has finished viewing the ad, then generate a token as a PHP POST variable?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are looking for. But just create an account and try it out yourself and you will see what you can see from users interactions.

Comment: @Andreas what I mean is that I want to give the visitor a reward for viewing the ad, but I want to check to make sure that the visitor has finished viewing the ad (for example, a video ad) before giving the reward.